# An example of Higman

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

[image]

The theorem is from Tao's blog.
He showed that if G’ is a finite group containing four elements a,b,c,d obeying (1), then $a,b,c,d$ are all trivial.The relation (1) is as following:$ab=ba^2;bc=cb^2;cd=dc^2;da=ad^2$.

My question is: how to derive that ord(b) is divisible by multiplicative order of 2 modulo $p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=\text{ord}(b)$. We know $p\mid 2^m-1$, that is $2^m\equiv1\pmod p$.
The positive integers $m$ solving $2^m\equiv1\pmod p$ are the multiples of $k$ where
$k$ is the multiplicative order of $2$ modulo $k$, that is the least positive integer
with $2^k\equiv1\pmod p$. Therefore $k\mid m$.

Comment: I don't understand why $k\mid m$. If $m=lk+r,r>0$, how to get the contradiction?

Comment: Then $2^m\equiv 2^r\not\equiv1$ as $2^2,2^2,\ldots,s^{k-1}\not\equiv1$.